# Expand div to the right css

Tags: html, css

```css
.icon1 {
  float: left;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
    
.text1 {
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid red;
  right: 50px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class= "icon1"></div>
  <div class= "text1"></div>
</div>
```

I want to make the text1 div expand to the right, I think a screenshot will help: [image: https://gyazo.com/e0ac67dadf5a0c8b20de2508cd525862] 
Can you guys help me? I want the left triangle to be a rectangle without the left-bottom-corner.

Comment: I'm not sure what your expected result is. Also, you could make your code into a Stack Snippet.

Comment: this is kind of the point I want to reach: https://gyazo.com/01f8aa86563c036653cfd4cb011b7fbb

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use and `img` or `svg`? As it stands, to make that shape with CSS I think you'll need multiple elements, `pseudo` or otherwise. You might be able to use `clip-path` depending on what you're doing with the shapes.

Comment: I want to add text inside and edit if needed

Comment: Is the text supposed to follow the angled edge?

Comment: The text will be centered, the angled edge is just for porpuses of aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this works for you, just hacked this together real quick:

```css
.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}

.icon1 {
  float: left;
}

.icon1::before {
  content: " ";
  float: left;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 100px solid transparent;
  border-left: 100px solid #f00;
}

.icon1::after {
  content: " ";
  float: left;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  margin-left: -70px;
  border-right: 100px solid #f00;
  border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
}

.text1 {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 1em;
  line-height: 80px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #f00;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class= "icon1"></div>
  <div class= "text1"><p>I'm some text within a fancy box.</p></div>
</div>
```

Bazinga.

**EDIT:** Completely reworked this based on OP's newest picture reference. Didn't try it in any other browser, not sure if this will hold up well. Looking good for me on FF though.

Comment: I added an image the OP shared in the comments to their post, might be a helpful reference.

Comment: I am sorry if I missleaded u guys, I thank you very much for the help, but I would like tho have the text inside the box, like in the image. I need a bottom triangle and a rectangle with a angle sized in the left.

Comment: But... but the text is inside the box? What image are you referencing? I'm seeing two, none of them has text. I'm honestly confused.

Comment: a picture is worth more then 1000 words: https://gyazo.com/f5e56693bc21acda79d03068faa46ee6

Comment: Aaaah. Gotcha. Editing now.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH, I am a fan!